# It's what's within the two

Tags: mathematics, word, visual

**What is the answer to this puzzle?**

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The answer to the puzzle is

> **SINE**

Which we must use to solve it!

---

> Plotting a sine function, and taking just the intervals given (as hinted by the title) before rotating as instructed spells out the letters of 'SINE':
>
>  [image]
>
>  [image]
>
>  [image]
>
>  [image]
>
> Guess you could call it... *sine language* (I'll see myself out...)

Comment: +1 sine language